# Cross platform disk encryption solution without admin privileges

Tags: windows-7, osx, cross-platform, encryption, portable

I am looking for a cross platform (OS X 10.10 + Windows 7) encryption solution which can fully encrypt, decrypt and modify a USB disk (full disk encryption). Truecrypt does this, but you need admin privileges to run it.

Can anyone recommend an alternative (i.e. a portable application) which runs with only **standard user privileges** under Windows 7? I have full access to the OS X machine. Preferably open source, but I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Researching this turns out to be an increasingly frustrating issue - every existing solution has some drawback. I actually followed the link originally posted by @PathumAnjana, but have not found anything usable yet. [SecurStick](http://www.withopf.com/tools/securstick/) looks interesting, but the transfer rates are much too low. How do you guys use encrypted USB drives?

Comment: I'm pretty confident that you can't mix *cross platform* and *without admin privileges* to do disk encryption. A cross-platform solution to do this would need to be *installed* first. Usually this means installing a file-system driver and that certainly entails privileged access to the computer.

Comment: admin/root rights will be needed to access the disk at low-level to do full file-system encryption. If you don't have those rights you should use a virtual encrypted disk image

Comment: Note that TrueCrypt and similar things only need admin privileges for only one time if they're fully installed, then any user can run it without admin, if that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have no solution to fully encrypt the disk content, but you can look at
Keepass https://keepass.info/ which can store files inside the safe file and it has great cross platform support.
(You'll need to check performances)

(I'm not sure about Password Safe https://pwsafe.org/, but it's worth checking out)

Answer (score 0):

Disk encryption interferes with the system (TrueCrypt, VeraCrypt...), so it usually has to be installed and admin rights are required.

You can use encryption at file level without installation e.g. File Lock PEA, but this does not encrypt the whole stick.